# page/form cutting off at 100% height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I am working on building an options page for a small website I am working on, but I have run into a rather interesting error. The bottom of my form seems to abruptly cut off at 100% browser height as seen in this picture:

http://oi39.tinypic.com/fm8cia.jpg

As soon as I refresh the page (F5), the form completes and everything works fine as seen in this picture:

http://oi40.tinypic.com/9zqerc.jpg

After fiddling with it for a while, I have noticed that the issue seems to reside with my  tag, for when I remove it, the problem goes away.

Here is the code for my form tag:

```
    <form action="r_options.php" method="post">

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>OPT_MINADMIN</b> - Minimum level to view the control panel.</label>
<select name = "opt_minadmin" style="float:right;">
    <option value = "<?php echo $opt['OPT_MINADMIN']; ?>"><?php echo $opt['OPT_MINADMIN']; ?></option>
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    <option value = "3">3</option>
</select>

    <br><br>


<label id="edit_account_label"><b>OPT_MINEN</b> - Minimum level to edit the manager/homepage notes.</label>
<select name = "opt_minen" style="float:right;">
    <option value = "<?php echo $opt['OPT_MINEN']; ?>"><?php echo $opt['OPT_MINEN']; ?></option>
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    <option value = "3">3</option>
</select>

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>OPT_MINADD</b> - Minimum level to add users to the system.</label>
<select name = "opt_minadd" style="float:right;">
    <option value = "<?php echo $opt['OPT_MINADD']; ?>"><?php echo $opt['OPT_MINADD']; ?></option>
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    <option value = "3">3</option>
</select>

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>OPT_MINEDIT</b> - Minimum level to edit users in the system.</label>
<select name = "opt_minedit" style="float:right;">
    <option value = "<?php echo $opt['OPT_MINEDIT']; ?>"><?php echo $opt['OPT_MINEDIT']; ?></option>
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    <option value = "3">3</option>
</select>

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>OPT_MINDELETE</b> - Minimum level to delete users in the system.</label>
<select name = "opt_mindelete" style="float:right;">
    <option value = "<?php echo $opt['OPT_MINDELETE']; ?>"><?php echo $opt['OPT_MINDELETE']; ?></option>
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    <option value = "3">3</option>
</select>

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>OPT_MINPOINT</b> - Minimum level use the attendance system.</label>
<select name = "opt_minpoint" style="float:right;">
    <option value = "<?php echo $opt['OPT_MINPOINT']; ?>"><?php echo $opt['OPT_MINPOINT']; ?></option>
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    <option value = "3">3</option>
</select>

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>OPT_MINSG</b> - Minimum level to edit the sales goals.</label>
<select name = "opt_minsg" style="float:right;">
    <option value = "<?php echo $opt['OPT_MINSG']; ?>"><?php echo $opt['OPT_MINSG']; ?></option>
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    <option value = "3">3</option>
</select>

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>OPT_MINSCHED</b> - Minimum level to edit the schedule suite.</label>
<select name = "opt_minsched" style="float:right;">
    <option value = "<?php echo $opt['OPT_MINSCHED']; ?>"><?php echo $opt['OPT_MINSCHED']; ?></option>
    <option value = "1">1</option>
    <option value = "2">2</option>
    <option value = "3">3</option>
</select>

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>P_NOSHOW</b> - Points given per noshow.</label>
<input type="text" name="p_noshow" value="<?php echo $opt['P_NOSHOW']; ?>" style="width:28px;float:right;" />

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>P_CALLED</b> - Points given for calling in sick.</label>
<input type= "text" name="p_called" value="<?php echo $opt['P_CALLED']; ?>" style="width:28px;float:right;" />

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>P_LEAVE</b> - Points given for employees leaving early.</label>
<input type="text" name="p_leave" value="<?php echo $opt['P_LEAVE']; ?>" style="width:28px;float:right;" />

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>P_LATE</b> - Points given for employees coming in late.</label>
<input type="text" name="p_late" value="<?php echo $opt['P_LATE']; ?>" style="width:28px;float:right;" />

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>P_PUNCH</b> - Points given for employees missing a punch in/out.</label>
<input type="text" name="p_punch" value="<?php echo $opt['P_PUNCH']; ?>" style="width:28px;float:right;" />

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>P_PERIOD</b> - How long the points period is. (in days)</label>
<input type="text" name="p_period" value="<?php echo $opt['P_PERIOD']; ?>" style="width:28px;float:right;" />

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>SESSION_TIMEFUNC</b> - Use the timeout feature?</label>
<select name = "session_timefunc" style="float:right;">
    <option value = "<?php echo $opt['SESSION_TIMEFUNC']; ?>"><?php echo $opt['SESSION_TIMEFUNC']; ?></option>
    <option value = "true">true</option>
    <option value = "false">false</option>
</select>

    <br><br>

<label id="edit_account_label"><b>REG_NAME</b> - Who is this software registered to?</label>
<input type="text" name="reg_name" value="<?php echo $opt['REG_NAME']; ?>" style="float:right;" />

    <br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Options" style="margin:auto;" onclick="return confirm('Update Options?')" />

</form>
```

Here is the CSS for the ID edit_account_label:

```
#edit_account_label {
padding-bottom: 10px;
float: left;
```

}

This problem only occurs in Google Chrome (Version 26.0.1410.64 m), the code works fine in Internet Explorer 9 with no problems.

I apologize for my sloppy code, I am no professional.

Comment: Im not sure if this will resolve your issue, but add display: block; and clear: both;'

Comment: I dont know if this is the problem, but id must be unique. If you have more than one object with the same style, use class.

And in css use .edit_account_label

Comment: I tried both of those methods, but neither seemed to work. I changes all the ID's to classes and added display:block and clear:both

Comment: Try to change the padding-bottom to margin-bottom. I think that in your case it will not make diference.

Comment: Is there a live site of this so I can test it on my chrome to see if I experience the same.  This way I can debug with developer tools also.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was at lunch. I tried to change the padding-bottom to margin-bottom, but it did not do anything. As for a live site, I have uploaded it to my website and it can be seen here: http://walnutcreekhardware.com/test/admin/options.php. If prompted for a username/password, u=admin p=admin. If you click on the admin tab at the top and then click on the options tab in the sub menu, that is where you can see the problem. I also noticed that it worked about 2 times in a row and on the 3rd try, it gave me the problem again.